# Hitting a JavaScript Button in Selenium - Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

I'm working on automating a huge project using Selenium in Java. It's been going pretty smooth but I recently hit a bump. I'm trying to submit the WebElements for a [multi-select menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R67ZD.png) (see below), and then add or delete them from their respective lists, but Selenium is having a hard time doing so.

[image: img]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="multiselect_labels_field_research_year" class="multiselect_labels">
    <div id="label_unselected_field_research_year" class="label_unselected">Available Options:</div>
    <div id="label_selected_field_research_year" class="label_selected">Selected Options:</div>
    </div>
    <div id="multiselect_available_field_research_year" class="multiselect_available">
        <select name="field_research_year_unsel" multiple="multiple" class="form-multiselect field_research_year_unsel multiselect_unsel" id="field_research_year" size="10">
            <option value="258">2016</option>
            <option value="261">2019</option>
            <option value="262">2020</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <ul id="multiselect_btns_field_research_year" class="multiselect_btns">
        <li class="multiselect_add" id="field_research_year"><a href="javascript:;">Add</a></li>
        <li class="multiselect_remove" id="field_research_year"><a href="javascript:;">Remove</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-field-research-year-und">
        <label for="edit-field-research-year-und">Research Year </label>
            <select class="field_research_year_sel multiselect_sel form-select" id="field_research_year" multiple="multiple" name="field_research_year[und][]" size="10">
                <option value="258">2016</option><option value="261">2019</option>
                <option value="262">2020</option><option value="259" selected="selected">2017</option>
                <option value="260" selected="selected">2018</option>            
            </select>
    </div>
```

I can find and click the menu items fine, but adding or removing is becoming a big pain. First, I found the WebElements for "Add" and "Remove" (the green and red buttons) in HTML and tried clicking it with Selenium's `.click()`, I get an error that says

> "Element [...] is not clickable at (329, 19)."

When I tried to click the link portion (isolating the "<\a href=" as the WebElement) it takes me to the first JavaScript link on the page, not this specific buttons. Finally, I am using Selenium's JavaScript executor to try and click the buttons. Here is my code:

```
for (WebElement we : yearButtonsRemove.getOptions()) {
    System.out.println(we.getText());
    we.click();
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", yearDel);
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", yearDel);
}

for (WebElement we : yearButtons.getOptions()) {
    if (we.getText().equals("2018") || we.getText().equals("2019")) {
        we.click();
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", yearAdd);
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", yearAdd);
    }
}
```

But now no errors are brought up or irrelevant links followed, instead nothing happens. The proper elements on the list are selected, but using the JavaScript to "click" the buttons does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Exception type, You can solve it by using following click method:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement("Your target element").click().Perform();
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this simply clicks on the first Javascript Element on the page and takes me to another link at the top of the page.

Comment: So what is your target ?

Comment: My target is the "mutliselect_add" button in green, but when I use that code the settings button in the top right hand corner of the webpage is being clicked (and I've performed many tests to make sure the web-element being passed in is the proper one).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your scenario without using JavaScript Executor as below

1. Create two function `addResearchYear` and `removeResearchYear` as below
2. If some year needs to be added, then you can achieve by calling the `addResearchYear` method by passing the driver instance and year
3. If some year needs to be removed, then you can simply call the `removeResearchYear` method by passing the driver instance and year.

**Code:**

```
   public void addResearchYear(WebDriver driver,String year){
    //you can add the element list from Available List option. Adding can be done as below without using the JavaScript Executor
    WebElement availableOptions=driver.findElement(By.name("field_research_year_unsel"));
    Select select=new Select(availableOptions);
    select.selectByVisibleText(year);

    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@class='multiselect_add']/a")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='multiselect_add']/a")).click();
}

public void removeResearchYear(WebDriver driver,String year){
    WebElement selectedOptions=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='field_research_year_sel multiselect_sel form-select']"));
    Select select=new Select(selectedOptions);
    select.selectByVisibleText(year);

    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@class='multiselect_remove']/a")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='multiselect_remove']/a")).click();
}
```

Comment: This gives a 

"unknown error: Element <a href="javascript:;">...</a> is not clickable at point (326, 19). Other element would receive the click: <a href="/admin/config">...</a>"

Ironically, that "/admin/config" is exactly the URL I'm taken when I use the Action object to try and click the button.

Comment: You can add the explicit wait before doing the click action. I have updated the answer and changed the add/remove element locator to XPath from Class Name

Comment: So, the xpath is not locatable. When I pass in an object already made for the WebElement I get this message:
Element <li class="multiselect_remove multiselect-remove-processed" id="field_school_reference">...</li> is not clickable at point (326, 19). Other element would receive the click: <a href="/admin/config">...</a>

Weirdly, the "removed-processed" does not show up anywhere in the source code!

Comment: Whether you are getting the same error after using the updated code?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I think the JavaScript attaches to this button is causing some hangups and making Selenium think that it needs to run the first thing attaches to the <a href=javascript:;>

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so for whatever reason the problem with this was Simply the ChromeDriver. It kept ignoring the paths and such and would simply not allow interaction with things that were wrapped in . I switched into FireFox and Selenium has since had no issues.

Thanks all for the help!